# How to save one document or a file permanently inside collection of MongoDB with Springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

all! I'm working on a project with MongoDB and Spring Boot. I want to implement a feature so that once I start running the server, there will be a fixed item (or file) stored in the collection of the MongoDB database. I want to forbid remove operation for this collection from application. How could I achieve this function? If there is any ambiguity, please let me know.

Here is an example. Let's say that there is a collection called `Node`. This is the `schema`:

```
{
    "id": "xxxx",
    "value": "1",
    "left": "left_node",
    "right": "right_node"
}
```

I want to keep this data in the database once the server started.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be removed"? From application or directly from db? Also, Node collection is always single-valued or there may be more documents? Also, the value need to be updated on startup or should be inserted only once?

Comment: I want it cannot be removed from application and  it only insert once when the server startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you're using Spring Data Mongo, if you need to forbid delete operations on your collection, you can create a special repository interface and inherit the repository bean for that collection from that repository interface.

Declare a generic repository which allows only `save()` operation:

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SaveOnlyRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S save(S entity);
}
```

Note: Dont forget to annotate this generic repository with `@NoRepositoryBean` which is used to avoid creating repository proxies for interfaces that actually match the criteria of a repo interface but are not intended to be one.

And extend your repository bean for that collection from that interface. Also add a `existsByValue()` method for further checking during the application startup.

```java
public interface NodeRepository extends SaveOnlyRepository<Node, String> {

    boolean existsByValue(String value);
}
```

Then you can create a listener that listens for `ApplicationReadyEvent`

Within this listener you can check if the `Node` exists. If it doesn't, then you save a document.

```java
@Component
public class Listener {

    private final NodeRepository nodeRepository;

    public Listener(NodeRepository nodeRepository) {
        this.nodeRepository = nodeRepository;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        if (!nodeRepository.existsByValue("1")) {
            nodeRepository.save(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anything can be removed within a database. but you can manage that by create separate users with different `roles/privileges` when accessing the database. ref: [create-a-user-defined-role](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#create-a-user-defined-role)

but you can do it manually where you need to check the `_id|id` before or within operation delete,

ex:

```
db.document.delete({id: {$ne: 'xxxx'}}}
```